# The same code of Google Maps API does not work on another site

Tags: google-maps

Can someone please tell me why the Google Maps API does not work on my project?

My new website is: http://www.auto-escola.net

The API works perfectly fine on another project: http://emtaubate.com

I'm using the same code to draw the new map. I do not understand why it does not work.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. the code is not the same.  2. there are no `locations` in the second map (` var locations = [];`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a CSS-issue, the source is the setting `overflow:hidden` for `div` in http://www.auto-escola.net/css/estilo.css (Line 9)

Add this CSS:

```
#mapa div{overflow:initial;}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!